# String.replace with special characters noting working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have spent several hours trying to figure out what is going on here looking at stack overflow and elsewhere and I cannot figure out what is going on.  I would really appreciate any help!!

I need to make `document.write('< /div>');` go to -> `< /div>`

I've simplified it down to the simplest possible case with the html example below.

```html
<script>
var str = "document.write('</div>');";
str = str.replace("/document.write/g","");
console.log(str); //</div>
</script>
```

Comment: You wouldn't have a hard time to figure out if you had taken a look [at manuals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Comment: You say that but I have been on https://regexr.com/, W3Schools, and the MDN Web Docs for a long time.  I misunderstood in the Docs where the input had either be a string|regexp.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exclude the quotes and it works. It is being interpreted as a string literal because of the quotes, whereas a regular expression literal is expressed between plain `/`s.

Also, `.` needs to be escaped or it matches any other single character.

```html
<script>
var str = "document.write('</div>');";
str = str.replace(/document\.write/g,"");
console.log(str); //</div>
</script>
```

Comment: I'd still recommend escaping the `.`. It matches a literal dot (along with everything else), but I think OP did want the literal match.

Comment: But this matches `"document write"` and `"document-write"` and ... you get the idea

Comment: `str = str.replace(/document\.write\('/g,"")`

Comment: You don't need `g` flag. Also it seems OP made an update.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion on the `g` flag.  In my real life case I have multiple hits in the string.  I appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 3):

[`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) accepts either a string or a regex. If you are going with a string this should be:

```js
var str = "document.write('</div>');";
str = str.replace("document.write","");
console.log(str);
```